# Replace the name of a VB6 string variable inside a string by the contents of that string variable?

Tags: vb6, string-interpolation

**tl;dr**
Skip to **PROBLEM** below.

**CONTEXT**

In my algebraic math program a formula can be entered in the following forms (as lines of VB6 code). (Spaces within strings will be ignored):

```vb
formula1$ = "SUM (a,b,c)"
formula2$ = "SUM (x,y,z)"
formula3$ = "PRODUCT (a,x)"
formula4$ = "PRODUCT ((SUM (a,b,c)) , (SUM (x,y,z))) "
formula5$ = "PRODUCT (" + formula1$ +") , (" + formula2$ +")"
```

(a bit fiddly for the user, I know, but better on balance when dealing with long formulae).

The content of `formula5$` is then identical to the content of `formula4$`.

It is useful to have a variable `formula5_descr$` which when inspected/printed describes the specification of `formula5$` thus:

```vb
debug.print formula5_descr$ ' --> "PRODUCT (" + formula1$ +") , (" + formula1$ +")"
```

The code for `formula5_descr$` can be produced manually. However it is difficult to do and the user cannot be expected to do it.

I want to let the user enter a simpler form of code like:

```vb
formula5$ = "PRODUCT (formula1$ ) , ( formula2$ )"
```

Then the program could be modified to parse the formula string `"PRODUCT (formula1$ ) , ( formula2$ )"`and replace any string references (i.e. `formula1$` and `formula2$`) by the contents of the relevant strings (i.e. `SUM (a,b,c)`  and `SUM (x,y,z)`).

**PROBLEM**

And here is the problem - how in VB6 to replace the name of a string variable inside a string by the contents of that string variable?

(User Joel Coehoorn has pointed out that a process for this called **string interpolation** is available in newer languages, like VB14+, C#, javascript.)

Ideally there would be a function `REVEAL()` such that:

```vb
REVEAL("formula1$") --> "SUM (a,b,c)"
```

**NOTE**
The fact that a solution exists for VBA in MS Access does not mean that the solution automatically works for VB6. They are similar but distinct languages and an installation of VB6 will not necessarily have the same components installed as for MS Access.

Comment: You could leverage `CallByName` to implement the REVEAL method, although it would require implementing the variables as Properties.  This approach could also be used after you parse out the embedded formulas in formula5.

Comment: The 2 methods (using Collection and Script Dictionary) described for VBA in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646864/how-can-i-get-reference-to-a-variable-by-using-a-string-in-vba?noredirect=1&lq=1) also seem to work in VB6.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford - thanks but I'm working in a module and dont know how to use properties.... properties of what object?

Comment: They would be properties of the module, but `CallByName`  objects must be in a form or class.  So you would need to do a little restructuring of your app to make it work.

Comment: "In my algebraic math program a formula can be entered in the following forms (as lines of VB6 code)." Are these really being entered as CODE in the program itself?...or are they being entered in a User Interface Control like a TextBox or RichTextBox, by the user at run-time?

Comment: @Idle Mind re: "Are these really being entered as CODE in the program itself?" Yes, it is a messy informal scientific programming environment. The formulae can be very long and complex and require frequent revision.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford - Many thanks for the info. I'm currently going down the route of using Collections for the current problem. But I'm interested in trying out ```CallByName``` for other problems in future.

Comment: I haven't coded in VB6 in a very long time, but here is a "close" question using [CallByName() in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56836566/2330053).

Comment: @Idle_Mind - thanks, that is helpful.

Comment: @Idle_Mind How do you propose to use CallByName for properties that are defined at runtime by the user, like `formula1$`? VB6 does not provide for runtime definition of classes. Unless you create a class with predefined `formula1$` ... `formula100$` and say that these 100 formulas is all the user gets, you cannot use CallByName.

Comment: This question was (correctly) closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646864/, with the binding vote by the OP. It was then reopened by three unrelated people. I wonder why?

Comment: @GSerg If they are defined at run-time, then `CallByName()` will have zero use. Totally agree with you. It is still unclear to me, however, even after re-reading the question and comments several times over, if the "user" in this case is entering their "code" at run-time in a Form somehow, or if they are actually modifying source code.

Comment: @Idle_Mind My - as per my reply to you of 18th October at 0:12, yes, the formulae are written into source code before execution (or during execution in debug mode).  They could also be written into and read from an external flat text file.  Form entry is not used.

Comment: @GSerg I guess the reason for re-opening may be that my question is specific to VB6, whereas the "duplicate" which you cite includes MS Access in its context (which means that additional reference libraries would be available there, providing for example the Eval() function - which is not available in a minimal VB6 environment).

Comment: @steveOw I found that question, I verified that the solution relies on pure VBA and not the Access libraries, I then casted the close vote. There was no "may".

Comment: @GSerg. The fact that one of the solutions offered (so far) to the other question is also a solution to my question does not mean that the two questions are identical.  Another valid solution to the other question invokes `Eval()` which is not a valid solution to my question.  I used "may" in reference to why my question was re-opened.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford Eventually (after learning how to) I followed your suggestion (thanks!) of using Objects and Properties. I chose to define a new Class (in a new Class module) because it provided further benefits.  I also made a Collection to reference all the Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a dictionary to store your formulas by key.
After that just replace the formula names by the value of them.

```
Option Explicit

Dim dictFormulas As New Dictionary

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ReadLines Text1.Text
    PrintFormulas
End Sub

Private Sub ReadLines(strText As Variant)
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim strLines()  As String
    strLines = Split(strText, vbNewLine)
    For i = LBound(strLines) To UBound(strLines)
        AddFormula strLines(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddFormula(strLine As String)
    Dim strFormulaName      As String
    Dim strFormulaValue     As String
    Dim strItem             As Variant
    Dim strFormulaVect()    As String
    
    strFormulaVect = Split(strLine, "=")
    strFormulaName = Trim(strFormulaVect(0))
    strFormulaValue = Trim(strFormulaVect(1))
    
    For Each strItem In dictFormulas.Keys
        strFormulaValue = Replace(strFormulaValue, strItem, CStr(dictFormulas(strItem)))
    Next
    
    dictFormulas.Add strFormulaName, strFormulaValue
End Sub

Private Sub PrintFormulas()
    Dim strItem             As Variant
    For Each strItem In dictFormulas.Keys
         Debug.Print strItem & "=" & CStr(dictFormulas(strItem))
    Next
End Sub
```

Dictionary is part of Microsoft Scripting Library (SCRRUN.DLL) must be added as reference in Project > References

Comment: In my VB6 the first line gives `Compile error: User-defined type not defined`.  A working alternative is: `Set dictFormulas = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.

Comment: Took me a while understand the logic but now I see that at the end it should loop back to read the next line. This is a good solution to the problem :)

Comment: Sorry for the error `Compile error: User-defined type not defined`. Dictionary is part of  Microsoft Scripting Library (SCRRUN.DLL) must be selected in Project > References to be used without CreateObject.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called **string interpolation**, and vb6 is old enough is does not have **any** support for the feature. You'll need to do something else, like use a dictionary to map a key like `formula1$` to a value like `SUM (a,b,c)`, and then do manual replacements of keys to values in the final string.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about the name "string interpolation". I see that it is available in VB14+.  User jacsetta has already provided an answer using Dictionary and I have accepted it.